# React testing library does not finish function test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I got this mock code right here on stackoverflow, but it's not working, the test calls the handleLogout function, but it doesn't execute the navigate('/login'), it's like the test runs only until the api call and ends the test.

```js
//headerApp.tsx
const handleLogout = async () => {
     await api.post('auth/logout');
     navigate('/login');
}

//headerApp.test.tsx

const mockedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as any,
  useNavigate: () => mockedNavigate
}));


test('check logout', async () => {
    server.use(
        rest.post('http://localhost:2001/backend_ihm/auth/logout', (req, res, ctx) => {
            return res(ctx.status(200))
        }),
    )

    const { getByTestId } = render(
        <Router>
            <AuthProvider>
                <HeaderApp links={links} activeLink={{ route: 1 }} />
            </AuthProvider>
        </Router>
    );

    await screen.findByText('TESTE');

    const linkLogout = getByTestId('link-logout');

    fireEvent.click(linkLogout);

    expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login');
});
```

Comment: Normally any async assertions need to be made with in a `waitFor` block: `await waitFor(() =>  expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login'));`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @AviCohenNehemia helped me, this is the answer:

`await waitFor(() =>  expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login'));`